# Internet Explorer 11 replaces Authorization header

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, asp.net-web-api, owin

What would cause Internet Explorer to replace the HTTP header

`Authorization : Bearer <server-provided-token>`

with

`Authorization : Negotiate <some token>`

when making an AJAX request?

**Details**

In Internet Explorer, some AJAX requests that are configured to contain the header `Authorization: Bearer ...` are being sent by Internet Explorer with the header `Authorization: Negotiate ...` instead.

For example, Fiddler shows that the first two of three requests contain the `Authorization : Bearer...` header, while the third suddenly contains the `Authorization : Negotiate...` header. The first two requests are successful, and the third fails because the request can't be properly authenticated.

All of the requests are constructed using the same client-side code, and are made one after another (within the span of a second). I have verified that the `Authorization` header correctly contains the `Bearer` token in all three cases up until the point the request is provided to the browser.

Also, I'm not seeing the same behavior in Chrome; it's only occurring in IE.

**Request 1**

```
GET http://localhost/myapp/api/User HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Bearer oEXS5IBu9huepzW6jfh-POMA18AUA8yWZsPfBPZuFf_JJxq-DKIt0JDyPXSiGpmV_cpT8FlL3D1DN-Tv5ZbT73MTuBOd5y75-bsx9fZvOeJgg04JcO0cUajdCH2h5QlMP8TNwgTpHg-TR9FxyPk3Kw6bQ6tQCOkOwIG_FmEJpP89yrOsoYJoCfrAoZ7M4PVcik9F9qtPgXmWwXB2eHDtkls44wITF_yM_rPm5C47OPCvMVTPz30KwoEPi6fHUcL3qHauP-v9uypv2e48TyPHUwLYmNFxyafMhBx4TkovnRcsdLHZiHmSjMq0V9a2Vw70
Referer: http://localhost/client/login.html
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: localhost
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

**Request 2**

```
POST http://localhost/myapp/api/Permissions HTTP/1.1
Referer: http://localhost/client/#/Dashboard
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer oEXS5IBu9huepzW6jfh-POMA18AUA8yWZsPfBPZuFf_JJxq-DKIt0JDyPXSiGpmV_cpT8FlL3D1DN-Tv5ZbT73MTuBOd5y75-bsx9fZvOeJgg04JcO0cUajdCH2h5QlMP8TNwgTpHg-TR9FxyPk3Kw6bQ6tQCOkOwIG_FmEJpP89yrOsoYJoCfrAoZ7M4PVcik9F9qtPgXmWwXB2eHDtkls44wITF_yM_rPm5C47OPCvMVTPz30KwoEPi6fHUcL3qHauP-v9uypv2e48TyPHUwLYmNFxyafMhBx4TkovnRcsdLHZiHmSjMq0V9a2Vw70
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 1419
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

<Post Data Removed>
```

**Request 3**

```
GET http://localhost/myapp/api/UserPreferences/Dashboard HTTP/1.1
Referer: http://localhost/client/#/Dashboard
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Negotiate YHsGBisGAQUFAqBxMG+gMDAuBgorBgEEAYI3AgIKBgkqhkiC9xIBAgIGCSqGSIb3EgECAgYKKwYBBAGCNwICHqI7BDlOVExNU1NQAAEAAACXsgjiBgAGADMAAAALAAsAKAAAAAYBsR0AAAAPVk1ERVZFTlYtU1JTQ0VSSVM=
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Connection: Keep-Alive
DNT: 1
Host: localhost
```

The requests are being made via the AngularJS `$http` service, and the back-end is ASP.NET Web API hosted in IIS.

Comment: Hi shrichards - did you ever figure this out?  I seem to be encountering the same issue with IE 11.

Comment: @JoshuaBarron I was never able to determine the root cause of the issue. I worked around the problem by creating a separate service with the single responsibility of issuing tokens. In IIS, that token service was configured to support both Windows and Anonymous authentication. The service that used the tokens for auth was then configured to use Anonymous authentication only in IIS (as auth was processed in via the tokens in the the middleware). This kept IE from attempting to perform integrated auth with IIS when the secured service was accessed.

Comment: Would you please give a more detailed example how you made this service (in github or pastebin). I lost more than two week with that problem and still can't find a work-around. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Martin - I already had the same setup that shrichards describes.  I followed http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/ to set this up.  I still was encountering this issue for some requests that the client was making (see my linked question).

Comment: To provide a better feedback about this issue it would be helpful knowing how the headers are added.

Comment: I'm seeing this too and I'm looking for a good solution. Following this thread and will post if I find a solution

Answer (score 21):

We had a problem where Internet Explorer was caching credentials. We could fix the problem by using the following script:

```
document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache', 'false');
```

see: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Perfect solution. Just add this line in index.html after html tag 
<script>document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache');</script>

Comment: This did not work .. for us at least.  It triggered re-prompting of the authentication on every request, and we still see the Authorization: Basic header overwriting our Authorization: Bearer header :(

Comment: This worked in our case. API: .Net Core 2.1; front-end: Angular; token based authentication. Added ClearAuthenticationCache right after authentication and before any other API calls.

Answer (score 6):

I've just come across this issue too.

What was odd is that it worked fine on my development machine, it was when I deployed it the issue arose.
Again it worked fine in Chrome, Firefox etc.

It turns out that the issue is that IE was detecting the site was on the localintranet zone and was therefore trying to automatically trying log on (it was set by group policy - this is an internal app).

My workaround was that (luckily) it was only autodetecting local intranet zone when using a server name that wasn't an FQDN (e.g. myserver) - but using the full A

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem in a knockoutjs application, it worked fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE.

I also used Fiddler and noticed that the first ajax call used Bearer as intended and returned successfully. But then IE started to loop and send the subsequent ajax calls over and over again with the Negotiate authorization instead!

In my case it was some sort of timing issue in IE, I solved it by making the ajax calls that loaded data during rendering synchronous.

```
    me.loadLimits = function () {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '/api/workrate/limits',
        headers: me.headers,
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

I also encountered this issue when I was kicking off multiple data loads in my angular app.

I worked around this by detecting the browser and if IE, delayed each request by 50ms based on the index of the call:

```
return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
 var delay = self.widget.useDelayLoading ? self.widget.index * 50 : 0;

 setTimeout(function() {
   restService.genericApi(self.widget.url, false).queryPost(json).$promise
    .then(
     function(r) { resolve(r); }, 
     function(e) { reject(e); }
    );
 }, delay);
});
```

Interestingly, when I used `$timeout`, I had to increase the delay to 100ms.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only seems to work when refreshing page NOT on initial page load. Still investigating...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the same issue and implemented a slightly random delay for each request and progressively delayed retries. This helped, but didn't fully solve the issue

Answer (score 3):

We had faced similar issue with angular and web api. Issue happens when the system tries to access some resource at root level which had Windows Authentication enabled. In our case, application was trying to get the favicon from IIS root. Once this request gets unauthorized, IE will try getting the resouce with negotiation header; though it fails again. But from this point onwards, IE keep sending negotiate header instead of our bearer token. This is due to the settings in IE, which I think is in Internet Options -> Advanced tab -> Enable Integrated Windows Authentication in the Security section (not sure, I forgot the exact stuff).

Fix was either give anonymous access to root level or to the resource location which app is trying to access (bad option) or have document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache', false); in the app.js file.

Comment: _document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache', false); in the app.js file._

What do you mean? My understanding is that code is only relevant to clear the authentication cache for Basic Authentication and not Windows.

And where you would put that code in your Angular app? It would have to be after you request from the IWA protected resources, but before you request from anon resources right?

Comment: @PeterM - I mean to have that code in your main module/controller. AFAIK, once a request hits 401 (when tries to access a resource protected using windows authentication), IE tries to hit that resource again using negotiate token. And afterwards, IE caches the token and sends that token for all the susequent requests. This is due to the setting in IE (if I remember it right) which I have mentioned in the answer. Could you please verify the behavior in network tab? Is the negotiate token going after the request is errored out with 401?

Comment: @PeterM - Are you still facing issue even after having clearCache code?

Comment: I didnt' try the clearCache code yet because I wasn't sure where to put it. we have some resources (html, js) we load that are IWA protected, but we also get auth tokens for our API from an IWA protected resource, so knowing when to clear that credentials cache is tricky. Also, feels like we'll end up getting prompted for login a lot more. I'll give it a try over the next few days

Comment: @PeterM - I would say just keep it globally, in you main module which is available throughout the application scope. You don't have to clear it everytime, this is one time configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, IE alternated between sending a bad request, followed by a good request on a second attempt, then followed by a bad request again and so on.

After trying several approaches to causing IE to retry - it appears that returning a 307 (Temporary redirect) with the same request url in the Location header solves the issue.

e.g. for a request to "http://myUrl/api/service/"

```
HTTP 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: http://myUrl/api/service/
```

IE retries the call with the proper data.

**Edit:** This method might be dangerous as it might create an infinite loop. A possible solution to work around it, is to return some counter as part of the url in the Location header and analyze it when receiving the call again.