# IE 11 request headers issue in case of 302 response code

Tags: angularjs, ajax, internet-explorer, http-headers, http-status-code-302

I am making http get request using angularjs and appending header "Authorization" via interceptor to the request, this request goes fine and returns a response with status  code 302.

Now when the browser makes the follow up request based on "location" header of the above request response, it removes "Authorization" header.

This is only happening in IE browser and I have verified it on IE11 and it is working fine on Chrome, Firefox, IE Edge.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs where Internet Explorer was caching credentials. We could fix the problem by using the following script:

```
<script>document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache', 'false');</script>
```

Or check it out on :

[Internet Explorer 11 replaces Authorization header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615850/internet-explorer-11-replaces-authorization-header)

Comment: I edited my answer,
Write it in your main html page.

Comment: when you send second request, it removes whole Authorization header? or it replaces it with some other token?

Comment: It removes the header, but I recently got it fixed by stopping redirection request and directly hitting the URL where it actually needs to go using reverse proxy. Thanks!!