# Setting xmlhttprequest Authorization header in IE11

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11

I have the following Javascript code to instantiate an XMLHttpRequest and download a file from a specified URI. The URI is protected with the need for an access token.

```
 var bearer, uri; // Set above, definitely correct
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

 xhr.open('GET', uri, true);

 bearer = bearer || null;

 if (bearer) {
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + bearer);
 }

 .... // download code
```

This works fine in Chrome, Firefox and several other browsers, but in IE11 fails to download the image. The server, while returning 200 in the working browsers, returns a 401, which I would expect to happen with Authorization header set. This can be seen in the IE network trace (as you can see, no Authorization header):

[image: "Request Headers" tab in IE network trace, showing no Authorization header set]

- I can replicate the failure in Postman using the request details given in the network trace. In this instance, when I add the Authorization header, it works.
- I have tried setting `xhr.withCredentials = true` after setting the request header, to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Apologies if this is a duplicate, I feel like it is but genuinely can't find any report of exactly the same problem. Cheers!

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615850/internet-explorer-11-replaces-authorization-header)

Comment: Sorry, i can't see how that is related. Anyone had this problem?